# ubuntu 16.04 l2tp over ipsec

Tags: ubuntu, ipsec, ubuntu-16.04, xl2tpd

i have vpn server and i use this tutorial to connect l2tpd over ipsec:
https://github.com/hwdsl2/setup-ipsec-vpn/blob/master/docs/clients.md#linux
http://www.jasonernst.com/2016/06/21/l2tp-ipsec-vpn-on-ubuntu-16-04/

When use status for ipsec then I have info is my connection is established (that great).
But i stop on last step "sudo route add default dev ppp0". PPP is point to point connection and when i use ifconfing, I have only two result

```
ens3      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr fa:16:3e:1e:e3:60
      inet addr:164.132.231.90  Bcast:164.132.231.90  Mask:255.255.255.255
      inet6 addr: fe80::f816:3eff:fe1e:e360/64 Scope:Link
      UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
      RX packets:135913 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:114613 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
      RX bytes:54418884 (54.4 MB)  TX bytes:9959003 (9.9 MB)

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback
      inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
      inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
      UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
      RX packets:26767 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:26767 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:1
      RX bytes:8941653 (8.9 MB)  TX bytes:8941653 (8.9 MB)
```

I dont have ppp. And now is my question. 
I need to create interface ppp or can I use my ens3 interface to dev route for vpn?

I not genius but when i use dev route on ens3 then my ip addres server change on ip vpn adress, then I block access to server whith ssh.

Answer (score 1):

Disclosure: I am the author of the GitHub repository you linked to.

The Linux client setup instructions have been re-written on 10/19/2016. Check out the updated instructions at:

https://github.com/hwdsl2/setup-ipsec-vpn/blob/master/docs/clients.md